# neo4j - cypher vs java api - for insertion which is faster

Tags: java, neo4j

As the title suggests, which is faster on insertion? Is it core api or cypher language?

This article says it's the api (though it's demonstrated query instead of insertion):
http://java.dzone.com/articles/get-full-neo4j-power-using

And the article is referring to cypher 1.9 where as we already have 2.0 now.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends if you run server or embedded. In the later case the embedded API is still faster but that will change soon. If you run server Cypher (with parameters and potentially LOAD CSV) is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it out and benchmark it yourself? In my experience, the java API is a bit faster, but that's normal. With the java API you specify exactly what you want, but Cypher needs to figure out things for you. This difference tends to make the java API slightly faster. I'm a big fan of Cypher nevertheless as it hides a lot of complexity. Also, don't use indexes if you don't need them, as they will make your inserts slower too.